# PHP Catch "Empty" Includes

Tags: php, include, require

We have a custom framework that we use, that allows us to `include` code in to other pages.  However, the header for this code is always printed, even if the `include` code doesn't output anything.  Is there a way that I can `exit`, or `return` something specific, that I can trap and catch via `include`/`require`, so that I can do the right thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Activate the output buffer, include the file and then check for its content:

```
ob_start();
include "file.php";
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

After that check for the content generated and either keep it or dump it.

Best wishes,
Fabian

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the most suitable solution, but it's a nice trick. You can actually use PHP-includes as functions and return values.

For example. Create a file called myinclude.php:

```
<?php

$a = 9192*9192;
return a;
```

Then create a second file and include the first:

```
<?php

$res = include("myinclude.php");
echo $res;
```

Yes, it actually works. See the [manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) for more details. Also note that if nothing is explicitly returned from the include file, include() will return "OK" (oddly enough). This works for require(), include_once() and require_once() as well.

Comment: This is an interesting method, and if I could give the right answer to both of you, I would, because using @halfdan's method in conjunction with yours got me *exactly* what I needed.

Thanks!